# How to get symbols from a particular font as array using jquery

Tags: jquery, unicode, fonts, symbols

I need to display symbols for a selected font as done in Microsoft word's Insert Symbol. 
If I can get the symbols for a font in an array, then, I can show them in a table as anchors to insert them into my web page's targeted text area when user clicks. I am new to web development.

Or if I can get r compute the unicode for those symbols then i can use them. I have rigorously searched for unicode of various symbols but its getting tedious as there are many symbols and I am not able to get code for all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You have to define the scope (and to show what you have done so far). Which characters do you need, and why do you want to take them from a specific font? Do you want 5 different characters, or 50,000? If you want a very general-purpose character insertion utility, you might use my Full Unicode Input utuility as such or as simplified: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8

Comment: I have gotto show around 3K symbols which are from fonts such as Bookshelf Symbol 7, Euclid Extra, Euclid Math One, Euclid Math Two, Euclid Symbol, Webdings, Wingdings, Wingdings2, etc. As I have mentioned the requirement is to provide an option to insert symbols similar to MS Word. All i need is how to get their unicode so that i can embed them in my UI